# count files with regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I want to count files using regex to match filenames.But My regex didn't match. My "F:\" has two files named "a(1).txt"&"a(1)(1).txt" .But regex only can match one of them,the count is 1. But when I change "()" to "-" in my regex and files' names.It can match all of them.I think the problem is in my regex.But I don't know why? 
here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File dest = new File("F:\\");
    File file = new File("E:\\a(1).txt");
    move(file, dest);
}

public static void move(File file, File dest) {
    //get file name
    String name = file.getName();
    int index = name.lastIndexOf(".");
    String realname = name.substring(0, index);
    String suffix = name.substring(index + 1, name.length());
    //get files in F:\
    File[] fs = dest.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File pathname) {
            //get File name
            String fname = pathname.getName();
            return fname.equals(name) || fname.matches(realname + "\\(\\d+\\)." + suffix);
        }
    });
    int count = fs.length;
    System.out.println(count);
    file.renameTo(new File(dest + realname + (count == 0 ? "." : "(" + count + ").") + suffix);
}
```

Comment: Typo: liatFiles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should learn debugging with IDE or at least printing values at sum checkpoint to narrow the source of issue.

Your pattern for `fname.matches()` is `a(1)\(\d+\).txt`. Round brackets are special symbols in regex to escape them you could use `java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(realname)`. It will change the pattern to `a\(1\)\(\d+\).txt`.

Thoughts:
input `file = a(2).txt` to match `a(2).txt` and `a(2)(1).txt` you could remove `fname.equals(name)` and modify regex to `fname.matches(Pattern.quote(realname) + "(\\(\\d+\\))*\\." + suffix)`. `*` means zero or more times inside round brackets; "." - dot is a special symbol and should be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

I think your regex should be

```
(\(\d+\))+\.
```

You also need to escape special character to use this regex in Java code as followed:

```
(\\(\\d+\\))+\\.
```

Comment: The issue is with `realname`.